# How can I programatically tap an AppBarButton?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, appbar, winrt-component

I have this code:

```
async private void InformUserOfRenameOption(string platypusName)
{
    CoreWindowDialog cwd = new CoreWindowDialog(String.Format(
        "This platypus has been given the default name {0}. Do you want to change it?", platypusName));
    cwd.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Yes", Id = 0 });
    cwd.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "No", Id = 1 });
    cwd.Commands.Add(new UICommand { Label = "Cancel", Id = 2 });
    cwd.CancelCommandIndex = 2;
    IUICommand cmd = await cwd.ShowAsync();
    //if (cmd.Id == 0) <= 'Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'
    if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Id) == 0)
    {
        appbarbtnRenamePlatypus.Tapped();
    }
}
```

...but my attempt to programatically tap the AppBarButton fails with the compile-time error: "*The event 'Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Tapped' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=*"

So how *can* I programatically tap the button or, more specifically, get its Button.Flyout Flyout to fly out?

Comment: I believe you can use [Automation Peers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj219211.aspx). Or you can make a custom control which extends from `AppBarButton`, as it's not `sealed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would refactor the code from the AppBar button's click handler into its own method, then you can call it from anywhere.

You could also consider using [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand.aspx) if you're feeling more adventurous -- this enables you to have any number of UI elements (eg [`ButtonBase.Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command.aspx)) or call it directly from code.